# Enquiry on the supremum of a set.

Tags: real-analysis

As a *prospective* undergrad doing pre-study in preparation of my future endeavours, i'm still to *fully* grasp the concept of the supremum of a set.

My question is:
                                                                              Suppose $\lim sup_{n \to \infty} f(n) = a$, does this imply that, for all sufficiently large $n$, $f(n) \leq a$ ?

From the relevant Wikipedia article, it seems obvious by definition, but i just want to be absolutely sure.

EDIT: For example, Gronwall's theorem on the asymptotic size of the divisor function states that $\lim sup_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n}=e^{\gamma}$, is it true that for sufficiently large $n$, $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n} \leq e^{\gamma}$ ? Or equivalently, is $e^{\gamma}$ also a limit superior in Gronwall's theorem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $\limsup_n f(n)$ instead of $\sup_nf(n)$, then the answer is no. Let $f(n)=1/n$. Then the limsup is zero, but it is never the case that $f(n)\le 0$. However, it is true that for every $\epsilon>0$, eventually $$f(n)\le \limsup f(n) + \epsilon\;.$$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, how about the case of Gronwall's theorem in the edit ?

Comment: The only way that $f(n)$ can eventually be less than or equal to its limsup is if $f(n)$ is eventually non-decreasing. Is this true for your sequence? If $f(n)$ takes values above its limsup infinitely often (e.g, if it is decreasing, or if it oscillates), then $f(n)$ won't be eventually less than or equal to its limsup.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$$
but $1/n>0$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Just in case: the supremum of a sequence and its limit superior can be different. The limit superior is the greatest accumulation point, and the superior doesn't have to be an acumulation point.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, how about the case of Gronwall's theorem in the edit ?